# Is it possible to use "zip()" with a step parameter?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, iterator

I would like to extract a very specific portion of a 2D array in Python using the `zip()` method (and avoid messy for loop logic). I'd like to use zip to achieve something like this:

```
>>> sub_matrix = list(zip([*grid[0:3]]*3))

# Desired output example (Option 1)
[".","4",".", ".",".","4",".",".","."]

# Desired output example (Option 2)
[[".","4","."],  
[".",".","4"],
[".",".","."]]
```

I am working with the 2D array below in Python on an interview practice problem.

```
grid = [[".","4",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
    [".",".","4",".",".",".",".",".","."],
    [".",".",".","1",".",".","7",".","."],
    [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
    [".",".",".","3",".",".",".","6","."],
    [".",".",".",".",".","6",".","9","."],
    [".",".",".",".","1",".",".",".","."],
    [".",".",".",".",".",".","2",".","."],
    [".",".",".","8",".",".",".",".","."]]
```

Part of solving the problem involves ensuring each 3 x 3 "region" in a sudoku game contains legal values. I'd like to use `zip()` to quickly extract a 3 x 3 portion of the matrix. For example, the top-left region would cause the tests to fail because it contains 4 twice.

[image]

I know I can subset the grid to get the first three rows as follows:

```
    >>> sub_grid = grid[0:3]
    >>> print(sub_grid)
    [['.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    ['.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
    ['.', '.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.']]
```

I modified the printing a little bit to make it obvious, but at this point, I'd like to zip the three arrays using a 'step' of 3, so that each new array will zip 3 values from each array before moving on to the next one.

In the [Python3 docs on `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) there is an excerpt on how I think this can be done, but I cannot get the desired output.

> The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed.
>   This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into
>   n-length groups using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`.

(For posterity, question is from CodeFights [will be hidden until unlocked](https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/SKZ45AF99NpbnvgTn/description))

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In numpy, this would be `grid[0:3, 0:3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No zip but
`[row[:3] for row in grid[:3]]`

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. I'll wait to see if there is a zip related answer before ticking the check-box. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`zip` does not support stepping through nested structures in that manner. Another alternative to the other answer is to use a `map` and extract those slices.

```
from operator import itemgetter
list(map(itemgetter(0, 1, 2), grid[0:3]))
```

or, if you prefer:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0:3], grid[0:3]))
```

If you're using python2, you can drop the extra `list(...)`.

As for what technique to use and why, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) thread on SO.

Output:

```
[('.', '4', '.'), ('.', '.', '4'), ('.', '.', '.')]
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

To get the blocks run this one-liner:

```
[reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, item) for l in [zip(*row) for row in zip(*[iter([zip(*[iter(row)]*3) for row in grid])]*3)] for item in l]
```

**Step by step explanation**

Let's first look at how to use `zip`:

```
chunks = [zip(*[iter(row)]*3) for row in grid]

[
    [('.', '4', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '4'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('1', '.', '.'), ('7', '.', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('3', '.', '.'), ('.', '6', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '6'), ('.', '9', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '1', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('2', '.', '.')],
    [('.', '.', '.'), ('8', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')]
]
```

You see how each row got split into chunks of size three. The rows should also be split, so we run:

```
blocks = zip(*[iter(chunks)]*3)

[
    (
        [('.', '4', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
        [('.', '.', '4'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('1', '.', '.'), ('7', '.', '.')]
    ), (
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('3', '.', '.'), ('.', '6', '.')],
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '6'), ('.', '9', '.')]
    ), (
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '1', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')],
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('2', '.', '.')],
        [('.', '.', '.'), ('8', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')]
    )
]
```

This gives us the blocks. For extraction it makes sense to first transpose them:

```
transposed_blocks = [zip(*row) for row in blocks]

[
    [
        (('.', '4', '.'), ('.', '.', '4'), ('.', '.', '.')),
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('1', '.', '.')),
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('7', '.', '.'))
    ], [
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')),
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('3', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '6')),
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '6', '.'), ('.', '9', '.'))
    ], [
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.')),
        (('.', '1', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'), ('8', '.', '.')),
        (('.', '.', '.'), ('2', '.', '.'), ('.', '.', '.'))
    ]
]
```

You see how each block is now on its own line. The last step is to merge each line into one list:

```
blocks_as_list = [reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, item)
                  for l in transposed_blocks for item in l]

[
    ('.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '1', '.', '.'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '3', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '9', '.'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'),
    ('.', '1', '.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.', '.'),
    ('.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.')
]
```

And we end up with the list of all blocks. Now you can check them against the sudoku rules.